# Samba Fedora problem with Windows. Permission issue

Tags: fedora, samba

http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/FastStart.html#id2554221

I followed this guide for Anonymous Read-Write Document Server...

THe workgroup is correct and i have set permission 777 to my shared folder...
I also called smbpasswd to add an existing user.

From windowse 7 i can see the folder but when i try to get in i get error[image]

Wasted 5 hours and no success... Tried with other security levels also not success..

Answer (score 1):

You likely have Samba blocked by your firewall.  To unblock it:

1. Locate *Firewall Configuration* on your *System* menu and run it, or run `system-config-firewall` on a terminal or by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.
2. Enter your root password when prompted.
3. Locate the *Samba* service.
4. Check the box to the left of it.
5. Click *Apply* on the toolbar.

[image: screenshot of firewall config]